# When does ActionResult get evaluated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I am a bit confused as to when ActionResult actually gets evaluated.

When using the Authorize attribute, I can see that if the user is not authorized, the result context gets set to an unauthorized result:

```
filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

However, the AuthorizeAttribute does not do the redirect, instead, it simply sets the context which just "flows" through the .NET pipeline until something converts that into a 401 header.

My question is what in .Net actually does the convertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am a bit confused as to when ActionResult actually gets evaluated.

ActionResult **get evaluated (not flushed to HTTP response or client)** after **IResultFilter.OnResultExecuting** and before **IResultFilter.OnResultExecuted**

Now what you are demonstrating with Authorize attribute is Action filter and it enable developer to alter/change action result within Action Filter life cycle. Here in Authorize attribute if user is not authenticated then **it is changing action result** to [HttpUnauthorizedResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpunauthorizedresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Now what you are saying that

> something converts that into a 401 header

but actually it is HttpUnauthorizedResult which set response header 401 while instantiating ActionResult object. Once ActionResult is instantiated it will be flushed to HTTP response pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of digging around, I see that all ActionResults inherit from the abstract class ActionResult, which has one abstract method: ExecuteResult

```
public abstract class ActionResult
{
    public abstract void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context);
}
```

It is this method that each action result implements with their own logic.

So for instance, JsonResult needs to specify the ContentType:

```
response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

While FileResult sets the "Content-Disposition" header:

```
context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", headerValue);
```